# How to get Min Check in time and Max check out time from table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table that stores check in and check out of employees. Now the data is stored in 2 different columns and in 2 rows something like shown below. If employee checks in on `2019-09-01 21:30:00` and checks out at `2019-09-02 08:45:00` it is showing total hours calculate in negative.

Here is data:

```
DROP TABLE TestAtte;
CREATE TABLE TestAtte(
    ID INT,
    TimeIn DATETIME,
    TimeOut DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO TestAtte VALUES(1, '2019-09-01 21:30:00', NULL);
INSERT INTO TestAtte VALUES(2, NULL, '2019-09-02 08:48:00');
INSERT INTO TestAtte VALUES(3, '2019-09-03 17:16:00', NULL);
INSERT INTO TestAtte VALUES(4, NULL, '2019-09-04 09:14:00');
```

My query is something like this

```
SELECT MIN(TimeIn) Checkin, MAX(Timeout) CheckOut
FROM dbo.TestAtte
GROUP BY CAST(COALESCE(TimeIn, Timeout) AS DATE)
```

The data should be something like this

```
TimeIn                      TimeOut
2019-09-01 21:30:00.000     2019-09-02 08:48:00.000
2019-09-03 17:16:00.000     2019-09-04 09:14:00.000
```

Comment: How can we tell that consecutive records belong to the same epmployee?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `LAG` function for this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LAG(TimeIn) OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut)) AS TimeIn2
         , TimeOut
    FROM TestAtte
)
SELECT TimeIn2, TimeOut
FROM cte
WHERE TimeOut IS NOT NULL
```

If the table contains record for multiple employees you need a `PARTITION BY EmployeeID` inside the `OVER` clause. The results will contain TimeIn = NULL for *orphan* TimeOut records.

Answer (score -1):

This uses Outer Apply to find the first time out after each time in.

```
SELECT CheckIn.TimeIn, CheckOut.TimeOut
FROM dbo.TestAtte AS CheckIn
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 1 TimeOut
FROM dbo.TestAtte AS AllOut
WHERE AllOut.TimeOut > CheckIn.TimeIn
ORDER BY AllOut.TimeOut ASC
) AS CheckOut
WHERE TimeIn IS NOT NULL
```